# IOS: View Translation Animation. Proper way.

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I'm implementing my own Navigation Controller and I'm faking the animation of adding the new view as in UINavigationContoller.

The following code works great, however if I move `-addSubview:`, before UIView animation call, it will animate in ios7, but not in ios6, the question is why? (I mean, why does it would make a difference, as animation will be scheduled and executed asynch, right? Or I might suppose It will somehow affect the starting state of animation?)

```
- (void)didAddViewControllerInNavigationStack:(NSArray*)navigationStack
{
    if (self.activeViewController) {
        [self.activeViewController viewWillDisappear:YES];
        [self.activeViewController viewDidDisappear:YES];
    }

    self.activeViewController = navigationStack.firstObject;
    if (!self.activeViewController) return;


    CGRect windowRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    windowRect.origin.x = windowRect.size.width;
    self.activeViewController.view.frame = windowRect;


    [self.activeViewController viewWillAppear:YES];

    [UIView transitionWithView:self.view
                      duration:0.32
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                    animations:^ { self.activeViewController.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]; }
                    completion:^(BOOL isDone){[self.activeViewController viewDidAppear:YES];}];

    [self.view addSubview:self.activeViewController.view];
    [UIView commitAnimations];


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of `transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion:`, it is said you should add the subview inside the animation block:

> The block you specify in the animations parameter contains whatever state changes you want to make. You can use this block to add, remove, show, or hide subviews of the specified view.

Also, you are calling `commitAnimations` without having called `beginAnimations:context:`. You are mixing things here. Block-based animation API does not need the begin-end API.

Your code should be:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.view
                      duration:0.32
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                    animations:^ { [self.view addSubview:self.activeViewController.view]; self.activeViewController.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]; }
                    completion:^(BOOL isDone){[self.activeViewController viewDidAppear:YES];}];
```

Comment: Thanks, great to know, I just have started playing with animation, 1 more small question, say, if I want to do the reverse thing, then -removeFromSuperview: should appear in the completion block?

Comment: Yes, because you want to remove the subview only once the animation is complete.